# Jenkins Failed Inspecting Plugin during development

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to develop a new Jenkins plugin that has a jar dependency to something from my Nexus repo.

When I try to launch the plugin in a debug mode to attach my IDE

```
mvnDebug hpi:run
```

I get the following error message:

```
Apr 25, 2016 11:04:37 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onTaskFailed
SEVERE: Failed Inspecting plugin C:\dev\Eclipse\vsync\work\plugins\vsync.hpl
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:230)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:160)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:168)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:132)
        at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.addPathFile(AntClassLoader.java:502)
        at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy$AntClassLoader2.addPathFiles(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:768)
        at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy.createClassLoader(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:278)
        at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy.createPluginWrapper(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:253)
        at hudson.PluginManager$1$3$1.run(PluginManager.java:254)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:282)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins$7.runTask(Jenkins.java:905)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:210)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1176)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:795)
```

I've checked my vsync.hpl file and see that it was properly generated, but the Libraries list is quite long due to all the dependencies that my jar has pulled in with it.

I suspect that Jenkins is failing trying to access/open one of those dependencies, but I have no idea which one it is.  Is there a way to get additional debug information out, to know which jar/zip file is failing?

Or baring that, is there a way I can put Jenkins itself (ie the Jetty container) in a debug mode and attach a debugger to that so I can step through the plugin load process and see what is failing?

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same Exception and in my case, it was caused by having a *pom* dependency in pom.xml, like below:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.main</groupId>
        <artifactId>cli</artifactId>
        <version>1.596.1</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
```

Which cause Jenkins try to extract pom file, which fails.